# Deliver message to all listening clients with Disque

Tags: disque

With Disque, is it possible to deliver a message to all clients listening on a specific queue in a fan-out fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible with Disque. You can grab a job and tell Disque to enqueue it again, thus giving other clients the chance to grab it, but that would be more an abuse of how Disque is designed, and it would be very complex to coordinate how the clients react when they grab a job they already processed.

For your use case, you can take a look at the pub/sub feature in Redis.

Comment: I already knew of that feature in Redis but since I'm using Disque to deliver all other messages I didn't want to add Redis into the mix just for this case